# CSS and JS files not working in Laravel/Vue.js with Themeforest template

Tags: html, css, laravel, vuejs3

I'm facing an issue while integrating a Themeforest template into my Laravel/Vue.js project. Here's a simplified version of my code in a Blade template file:

```
<html>
    <head> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/plugins/bootstrap.min.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/plugins/slick.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/plugins/slick-theme.css"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
        
    </head>
    <body class="antialiased">
        <div id="app"> 
        </div> 
        <script src="assets/js/plugins/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="assets/js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="assets/js/plugins/slick.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

I have verified that the file paths are correct and that the files exist in the specified locations relative to the Blade file. However, the CSS and JS files other than Bootstrap and style.css are not working as expected.

I'm using Laravel and Vue.js for my project. Could this issue be related to the way Laravel handles asset paths or Vue.js conflicts? I'm not sure where to start debugging or what could be causing this problem.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you checked that the files are loading correctly into your page? Watch your browser's Network tool while the page is loading, and check what HTTP response code you get for each JS and CSS file. A 200 response indicates it loaded correctly. Other codes may indicate an issue. That is the sort of basic check you should have done already, I hope? "not working as expected" gives us pretty much no indication of what you've checked or precisely what the issue is, so there's no much we can do with such vague information, apart from asking you to be more specific. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson yes i checked 200 response show.

Comment: You mean it shows 200 for all the JS and CSS files, every single one? Ok then, if that's the case then presumably you have a slightly more subtle problem. But we don't know what that is, because we don't know what you're expecting to happen, or what exactly is happening instead. All we know is it's not doing everything you wanted it to. Again, you'll need to be a lot more specific. Have you also checked the Console for any errors / clues?

Comment: @ADyson facing an issue where a JavaScript function that was working perfectly in an HTML/CSS setup is not functioning correctly after converting it into a Laravel/Vue.js project. Surprisingly, there are no error messages in the console.

Comment: Ok. We can't help you without a [mre] and a precise description of the issue. See also [ask]. No-one can fix vague problems in invisible code, sorry :-)

Comment: Have you shared the compiled blade html or the code directly?